# How to Integrate Color Picker Function into Dynamic Text Field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently facing some problems with creating dynamic text field which integrated the colorpicker function.

Here are the HTML code:

```
<div id="color_div">
    <input type="text" name="color" id="p_color" maxlength="7" value="#365EBF">

    <a href="#" id="addColor">Add Color Picker</a>
</div>
```

The javascript function of creating dynamic text field is work fine:

```
/* -----------------------------------------------
                    Add Multiple Color
----------------------------------------------- */
        var multiple_color = 1;

        $('#addColor').click(function() {
                multiple_color++;
                event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;  
                $('#color_div').after('<div id="color_div2"><input type="text" name="color[]" id="p_color" maxlength="7" value="#365EBF"><a href="#" id="remColor">Remove</a></div>');
                return false;
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#remColor', function() {
            event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
            $('#remColor').parents('#color_div2').remove(); 
            return false;   
        });
```

And this are the codes for calling color picker function, but its only working for the text field that exists at the beginning. For the dynamic created text field, it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#p_color').colorpicker()
})
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ids should be unique so you will need to change the id of your second colour picker.

Second you then need to instantiate the colour picker on the dynamic item once you have added it.

I would do something like this:

```js
var multiple_color = 1;

$('#addColor').click(function(e) { // include the e in the function so you can use e.preventDefault()
  e.preventDefault();  
  multiple_color++; // use this to keep ids unique
  
  var id = 'p_color' + multiple_color; // id of input
  
  $('.color_div')
      .last()
      .after('<div id="color_div' + multiple_color + '" class="colour_div"><input type="text" name="color[]" id="' + id + '" maxlength="7" value="#365EBF"><a href="#" class="remColor">Remove</a></div>');   // change link id remColor to class and add color_div class to div
      // add new div after the last div  - if you want to add it after the first colour picker then just put it back to use the id of the first colour picker div

  $('#' + id).colorpicker(); // instantiate color picker on the new object you just added
});

$(document).on('click', '.remColor', function(e) {  // change selector to class
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('.colour_div').remove(); // remove current div
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color_div1" class="color_div"> <!-- add color_div class -->
    <input type="text" name="color" id="p_color1" maxlength="7" value="#365EBF">

    <a href="#" id="addColor">Add Color Picker</a>
</div>
```